# How to correct for delays in a PAM-X signal with orthogonal CDMA?

Tags: digital-communications, resampling, software-defined-radio, gnuradio, spread-spectrum

I have a receiver which receives data bits at a rate of 5kbit/s. The number of data bits per burst is low (say, 16 bits). These databits are obtained **after despreading** the incoming signal using an orthogonal CDMA code (8-bit Walsh Haddamard code). This implies that the incoming chip rate is 5*8=40 kchips/s. The actual signal I get from the ADC is an upsampled I/Q version at complex baseband, sampled at a certain sampling rate (e.g. 5Msps).
I implement the system in gnuradio (but the question is general).

I figured that instead of explicitely performing the despreading via multiplication and summing up the values, it is easier to use the cdma_code as a filter. This can be interpreted as a form of matched filtering (I think). However, this simplified version misses an important point: Timing. In the worst case, the downsampling happens at the symbol or bit transitions and the result is garbage. Hence I use clock synchronization based on polyphase filtering (https://wiki.gnuradio.org/index.php/Polyphase_Clock_Sync).

However, I have a multi-stage downconversion system here: I am able time-synchronize the *chip stream* with the Polyphase Clock Sync block. However, when I apply despreading (by filtering the chip stream with the time-reverse chip sequence and decimating) I again have a time alignment issue: the 8 bit chip code has to be aligned with the input signal.

I tried using the polyphase clock sync block where the matched filter combines the matched filter and the CDMA code as suggested in Marcus Müllers answer below. However, I think such a system is unable to find the correct offset.

Consider this simple MATLAB experiment which generates a sample stream encoding $[1,-1,1,1]$. The receiver simulates the "Polyphase Clock Sync" block in gnuradio by finding the time shift that minimizes $(b\cdot db/dt)_{t=nT}$ where $b$ is a shifted version of the input signal:

```
fs = 400e3;
fchip = 40e3;
% test bits 1,-1,1,1  and add zero-padding
testdata = [ 0 0 0 0 0 1 -1 1 1 0 0 0 0 0 ]';
% 8-bit Walsh-Haddamard
H = [ 1, -1, 1, -1, -1, 1, -1, 1 ];
SF = size(H,2);
Nbits = size(testdata, 1);

% the test data at the chip rate
testdata_cr = upfirdn(testdata(:,1), ones(1, SF), SF);

% the modulated chip stream
chips = testdata_cr .* repmat(H(1,:)', Nbits, 1);

% upconvert chip stream to sample stream using rrcos (for simplicity)
hup2 = rcosdesign(0.8, 15, fs/fchip);
samples = upfirdn(chips, hup2, fs/fchip);

%% RECEIVER
% define the matched filter (=rrcos + CDMA code) at the receiver
mfilt = upfirdn(H(1,:), hup2, fs/fchip);

x = filter(mfilt, 1, samples);

% This implements a simplified version of the Polyphase Clock Sync block
delays = -fs/(fchip/SF)/2:1:fs/(fchip/SF)/2;
res = zeros(length(delays), 1);
B = zeros(length(x), length(delays));
for m=1:length(delays)
    B(:,m) = circshift(x, delays(m)); % works because of zero padding
    %plot(b);hold all;
    v = B(:,m) .* gradient(B(:,m));
    res(m) = sum(v(1:fs/fchip*SF:end)); % sum samples
end
% find the delays where b * db/dt is approximately zero
zeroxing = @(v) find(v(:).*circshift(v(:), [-1 0]) <= 0);
idx = zeroxing(res);

%plot(delays, abs(res), '-', delays(idx), res(idx), 'o');
% plot the candidates
plot(B(1:fs/fchip*SF:end,idx))
```

Since this block uses $b$ as an objective function (using the delay index that minimizes the sum of the samples of $b\cdot db/dt$), there must be a global optimum which finds the correct sequence $[1,-1,1,1]$. However, there are multiple optimum delays (values close to zero):

[image]

Now I plot the resulting bit stream for all the delays where the objective function is close to zero and only one shift gives the correct $[1,-1,1,1]$ pattern:

[image]

I can reproduce this experiment with a gnuradio model as well (https://www.dropbox.com/s/48fy30vwkivahqz/test_polyphase_clock_recovery_cdma_direct.grc):

[image]

My question is: How to implement such a system and how would one do this in practice?

Comment: I've not heard of Walsh-Hamming, but of Walsh-Hadamard; possible you mean the latter? Either way, why does a spreading system imply PAM?

Comment: by the way, when applying your CDMA sequence as filter, don't forget to time-invert it!

Comment: @MarcusMüller My bad, Walsh Haddamard (fixed). Ok it does not imply PAM. But I assume the senders send NRZ/PAM-2, so the sum of them is multilevel PAM. And thanks, I have time-inverted it.

Answer (score 1):

Couple of observations:

1. you can of course also correlate with the already pulse-shaped CDMA sequence as a whole – it's a long filter, then, but that (in AWGN) will essentially give you the basis of a maximum likelihood receiver.
2. Commutativity of convolution: Doesn't matter whether you pulse shape filter -> CDMA sequence filter or CDMA sequence filter -> pulse shape filter. The result is the same (and the same as if you first convolved CDMA sequence and pulse shape, and the signal then with that – see 1.)

In either case, you'd only do one synchronizer.

Comment: Are you sure about that? I think the issue is less commutativity but time variance (where samples are taken). 1.) https://snipboard.io/6mworp.jpg shows the output of such a long filter (=CDMA code, upsampled with the matched filter) **without** decimation. An ideal polyphase clock sync would pick the peaks as sampling points. But which peaks would be impossible to decide (without further knowlede). If I use the 8-bit CDMA code, then we'd need to make sure they align properly across 8 chips. Either I am missing something or we need two synchronizers.

Comment: 2.) https://www.dropbox.com/s/48fy30vwkivahqz/test_polyphase_clock_recovery_cdma_direct.grc (screenshot https://snipboard.io/5qPWjb.jpg ) shows a simple demo in gnuradio. The delay (in sample units) can be adjusted with a QT GUI Range. It can be seen that the polyphase sync block is able to produce the right output ($[1,-1,1,1]$) when the delay is much smaller than the chip duration. However, beyond that, the clock sync just does not know when the 8-bit code is aligned correctly with the incoming signal. That's the reason for my question: How would this be done by an actual system?

Comment: 3.) Regarding #1: When the oversampling ratio exceeds 4 and the CDMA 8-bit, gnuradio says `sched: <block pfb_clock_sync_ccf (3)> is requesting more input data than we can provide. ninput_items_required = 19280. max_possible_items_available = 8191. If this is a filter, consider reducing the number of taps.`

Comment: yes, I'm sure. You never mentioned a time-variant channel. And commutativity holds, and so does chain rule, so my 1. is definitely true.

Comment: and re your 3.): GNU Radio's scheduler error message is pretty explicit, isn't it?

Comment: I don't know how to best discuss this but I revised my question completely and I hope it is more clear now. Maybe it was unclear and we were talking of different things. I get your point that they are commutative but I think this was not exactly I was asking ... ultimately I want to get my original bits back and I don't see how I can properly synchronize them with one synchronizer. No time-varying channel.

Comment: I somewhat understand the message (the polyphase sync block needs to many samples at once due to the long filter but they're not available) but it also makes me doubt that this would then be the right approach? All I found in google was "fix your flow diagram" which doesn't tell me much. If I assume long filters are valid (I think they are) then my flow diagram (see my question) seems correct.